# How to prepend a prefix to variables sourced from a config/env file

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have this situation:

```shell
source local.env
run_my_app
```

In `local.env`, I have a bunch of environment variabless that pertain specifically to `run_my_app`, like this:

```shell
es_protocol="http"
es_host=0.0.0.0
es_port=9200

mongo_protocol=mongodb+srv
mongo_host=foo.cluster.mongodb.net
mongo_port=80
mongo_user=foo

rabbit_protocol=ampq
rabbit_host=foo.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
rabbit_port=5672
rabbit_user=rabbitmq
```

Instead of adding a prefix `my_app` to every variable in the file which is redundant and noisy, I want to add a prefix using a shell program, something like this:

```shell
source <(add_var_prefix 'my_app' local.env)  ## *note below
```

Does anyone know how to implement a Bash function like `add_var_prefix` that can do 2 things:

1. add the prefix to all variables in the `local.env` file
2. export the variables instead of just sourcing

- note that `source <(xyz)` won't work because source doesn't work with process substitution for some ungodly reason

Comment: Remember, shell command streams are just text files.  Have you tried `sed`?

Comment: @JimL. not sure I follow what you mean, all I know is that source cannot work with process substitution, so I will add a comment to OP

Answer (score 2):

Here is a naive solution using `sed`:

```
source <(sed 's/[^=]\+=/export my_app_&/' local.env)
```

I call this "naive" because I assume that each line containing an equal sign is a variable assignment, and I do not take into account any fancy formatting, like multi-line variables or several assignments on the same line.

Comment: sadly source doesn't work with process substitution, like the 4th time I have tried this, every 18 months I forget that bash cannot do that, it's the WORST

Comment: I've just tried it with Bash 5.1.16 and  this works as expected. I also did this several years ago, probably with Bash 4. Try it: `source <(printf 'echo It works')`

Answer (score 1):

A slight addition to @xhienne's answer, with a regexp that will recognize `#` at beginning-of-line as a comment, and some QED exercises showing that both sourcing and exporting work using this techique.

From a fresh shell:

```
$ set | grep prefix
$ bash -l
$ prefix=my_prefix
$ source <(sed -Ee "s/^([^#])/${prefix}_\1/" local.env)
```

I can now confirm that my environment has several lines of content matching "prefix":

```
$ set | grep prefix
my_prefix_es_host=0.0.0.0
my_prefix_es_port=9200
my_prefix_es_protocol=http
my_prefix_mongo_host=foo.cluster.mongodb.net
my_prefix_mongo_port=80
my_prefix_mongo_protocol=mongodb+srv
my_prefix_mongo_user=foo
my_prefix_rabbit_host=foo.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
my_prefix_rabbit_port=5672
my_prefix_rabbit_protocol=ampq
my_prefix_rabbit_user=rabbitmq
prefix=my_prefix
```

Opening a subshell and checking again confirms that none of those variables
are exported:

```
$ bash -l
$ set | grep prefix
$ ^D
logout
$ ^D
logout
```

Back to a clean shell:

```
$ set | grep prefix
$ bash -l
$ prefix=my_prefix
```

This time we'll export all those variables:

```
$ source <(sed -Ee "s/^([^#])/export ${prefix}_\1/" local.env)
```

Here they are in the parent shell:

```
$ set | grep prefix
my_prefix_es_host=0.0.0.0
my_prefix_es_port=9200
my_prefix_es_protocol=http
my_prefix_mongo_host=foo.cluster.mongodb.net
my_prefix_mongo_port=80
my_prefix_mongo_protocol=mongodb+srv
my_prefix_mongo_user=foo
my_prefix_rabbit_host=foo.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
my_prefix_rabbit_port=5672
my_prefix_rabbit_protocol=ampq
my_prefix_rabbit_user=rabbitmq
prefix=my_prefix
```

And if we open a child shell, the variables appear there also:

```
$ bash -l
$ set | grep prefix
my_prefix_es_host=0.0.0.0
my_prefix_es_port=9200
my_prefix_es_protocol=http
my_prefix_mongo_host=foo.cluster.mongodb.net
my_prefix_mongo_port=80
my_prefix_mongo_protocol=mongodb+srv
my_prefix_mongo_user=foo
my_prefix_rabbit_host=foo.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
my_prefix_rabbit_port=5672
my_prefix_rabbit_protocol=ampq
my_prefix_rabbit_user=rabbitmq
$ ^D
logout
$ ^D
logout
```